# Bones Not Connected?

Tags: animation

I've made this model with bones but when i try to animate the model by moving or rotating a bone it disconnects from another. How do i get a bone so when i rotate it its still connected to another bone?

Bone before rotation:

[image]

Bone after rotation:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening i thought bones were supposed to be connected. I have been researching this problem for hours but this nothing about this, it doesn't look like anyone else has this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go to edit mode, select the two bones, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>> Connected.

Also when you have added a bone, and then you go to edit mode. Select the tip of the bones and extrude it with <kbd>E</kbd>, then the bones are automatically parented to each other.

Comment: Thanks this worked but why weren't they connected properly, i extruded the bones out of the others so they should of been connected right?

Comment: @Awesome Name, if you extruded it out of the bones it should have been connected.

Comment: I must of accidentally disconnected it somehow